# Looking for an RTSP test server I can run locally

Tags: rtsp, onvif

RTSP is fading in popularity these days, however as it's part of the ONVIF standard I'm stuck with it. For test & dev purposes I'm looking for a server that outputs a test signal/image/movie to any RTSP client that connects.

I'm aware of Cloud services that do this, however I need something local .. for reasons(1).

Given the lack of current need for RTSP all the tools I've tried so far suffer from code rot, or have dependencies that do.

I'm developing on macOS and the Raspberry Pi - is there a turnkey solution I can deploy on either box?

--
1: the NVR in use will only connect to an RTSP stream on the same host as the ONVIF web services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: live555MediaServer fits the bill very nicely.

It depends only on openSSL and the code is free [available to download](http://www.live555.com/liveMedia/public/). When working on a mac it's included in the [`openrtsp` home-brew formula](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/openrtsp#default). Use `sudo apt-get install livemedia-utils` to get it on your Raspberry Pi.